# load pmml (generated by sklearn) in spark to predict but get error

Tags: pmml

I am following instruction [jpmml-evaluator-spark](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator-spark/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/jpmml/evaluator/spark/PMMLTransformerTest.scala) to load local pmml model 
my code is like below

```
import java.io.File
import org.jpmml.evaluator.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql._

// load pmml
val new File(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("random_forest.pmml").getFile)

// create evaluator 
val evaluator = EvaluatorUtil.createEvaluator(pmmlFile)
```

I cannot show the error message directly, so I put it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEiQ1.png)

guesses:

there are some reasons i think may cause this problem

1, "jpmml-evaluator-spark" does not support PMML4.3, even if the author said new version 1.1.0 has already supported PMML4.3

2, there are some problems about my "random_forest.pmml", because this file is from others

**Note:**

development environment

spark 2.1.1

scala 2.11.8

and I run on the local, mac system version is OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6

Answer (score 0):

You are using Apache Spark 2.0, 2.1 or 2.2, which has prepended a legacy version of the JPMML-Model library (1.2.15, to be precise) to your application classpath. This issue is documented in [SPARK-15526](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15526).

Solution - fix your application classpath as described in JPMML-Evaluator-Spark documentation (alternatively, consider switching to Apache Spark 2.3.0 or newer).

Comment: my spark version is 2.1.1 and i cannot change it since this version is same as production environment. i will try the solution you provided, and give the reply later

Comment: @Binbin Then install Spark 2.3.0 locally to see that JPMML-Evaluator-Spark has no problem scoring PMML 4.3 documents.

Comment: thanks. follow your advice. i upgraded spark from 2.1.1 to 2.3.1, then the problem was solved. And i also find a link from java pmml API devloper also said the same solution. here is, https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator-spark/issues/20

Answer (score 0):

Another option of using PMML in Spark is [PMML4S-Spark](https://github.com/autodeployai/pmml4s-spark), which supports the latest PMML4.4, for example:

```
import org.pmml4s.spark.ScoreModel

val model = ScoreModel.fromFile(pmmlFile)
val scoreDf = model.transform(df)
```